# How to make firebase onDataChange() stop to call android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, chat

I am developing an chat module in my project. For the chat module I am using fire base. In my project there is a requirement like when two users is chatting if user A blocks user B the user A should not get any kind of message from user B in the same way user B should not get any message from user A but still they can able to send the messages but receiver should not receive ref whats app.I am using fire base recyclerview adapater for displaying chat messages. To overcome this problem what i did was when user is blocked I am just making the recyclerview params as 0 when I receive the message in blocked case due to this my recyclerview is just moving up and down which is little annoying. Please find my code snippet below with my fire base structure

```
case RECEIVER:
                        try {
                            listener = new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    try {
                                        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                                            Conversation conversationData = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversation.class);
                                            if (!conversationData.isBlocked) {
                                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
                                                layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                                                layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                                                holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                                HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                                hashMap.put("isseen", true);
                                                dataSnapshot.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                                                ((FirebaseConversationViewHolder) holder).messageText.setText(conversationData.getMessage());
                                                if (conversationData.getTimeStamp() != null) {
                                                    ((FirebaseConversationViewHolder) holder).timestamp.setText(TimeFormat.getTimeStamp(conversationData.getTimeStamp(), TimeFormatType.FORMAT_DESCRIPTION));
                                                }
                                                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                                                        .load(getResources().getString(R.string.image_loading_url) + friendProfilePath)
                                                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile).into(((FirebaseConversationViewHolder) holder).userProfile);
                                            } else {
                                                //firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
                                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
                                                layoutParams.height = 0;
                                                layoutParams.width = 0;
                                                holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                                //conversationDatabaseReference.child(firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(null);

                                                //holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
                                            }

                                        }

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Log.d("cancel", "database");
                                }
                            };
                            conversationDatabaseReference.child(firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Crashlytics.logException(ex);
                        }
                        break;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to layout **gone** instead of set **height & width 0**.

```
try {
            listener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    try {
                        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                            Conversation conversationData = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversation.class);
                            if (!conversationData.isBlocked) {
                                //Your Code
                            } else {
                                //Hide the layout
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d("cancel", "database");
                }
            };
            conversationDatabaseReference.child(firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Crashlytics.logException(ex);
        }
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: What issue generated?

Comment: try to layout gone in else part

Comment: if i use layout gone then it is creating empty spaces

Comment: In that case u can show user is blocked or as u want